# Why can't read AWK program as heredoc

Tags: awk, sh

Why are the below two similar scripts have different behavior?

The following command:

```sh
{ echo a; echo b; } | awk $(cat <<'EOF'
    {print $0}
EOF
)
```

fails with this error message:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>>  <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
        missing }
```

However, if I store the heredoc in a variable first, it works:

```sh
cmd=$(cat <<'EOF'
    {print $0}
EOF
)
{ echo a; echo b; } | awk "$cmd"
```

produces:

```
a
b
```

I'm using Mac OS. I can repro using both zsh and POSIX `sh`.

Comment: Just curious - why are you considering doing either of those things?

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: use quotes around the '$(cat ... )' to prevent bash from parsing the output of `cat` (the awk program), and treat it as a single argument

```
{ echo a; echo b; } | awk "$(cat <<'EOF'
    {print $0}
EOF
)"
```

Long Answer: The output of the `$(cat ...)` is a awk program '(print $0}'. Without quotes, bash will expand the $(cat), and produce:

```
   awk {print $0}
```

Taking '{print' as first argument (the program), and taking '$0}' as second argument (the name of the input file). To get the combined string to be considered as one argument, quotes are needed. With quotes the expanded command (and command substitution) is

```
   awk "{print $0}"
```